# How to label and extract audio using timestamp annotation

Tags: audio, timestamp, extract, librosa, labeling

I would like to label and then extract certain segments of an audio file (audio.wav). The start and end times of the segments are given by the DateTimeStamp (first column) and the duration of action in milliseconds (third column) in another file, the annotation file (annot.csv):

```
DateTimeStamp           Action  Duration of action in milliseconds
04/16/20 21:25:36:241   A       502
04/16/20 21:25:36:317   B       2253
04/16/20 21:25:36:734   X       118
04/16/20 21:25:36:837   C       10
04/16/20 21:25:37:537   D       797
04/16/20 21:25:37:606   X       70
04/16/20 21:25:37:874   A       1506
.                       .       .
```

The audio.wav file starts at the time of the first DateTimeStamp of the file annot.csv. How can I use the information in the annot.csv file to label and extract a certain segment (e.g. corresponding to Action X) from the audio.wav file?

I attempted to solve it with the librosa and pyAudioAnalysis packages, but I couldn't find the information required.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing here is to compute the start and end (in audio samples indices) for each specified segment.

This can be done by first converting milliseconds to seconds, and then to sample indices by multiplying with the sample rate of the audio.

But in general I would recommend using Pandas datetime and timedelta functionality whenever dealing with time-series such as these. Below is some example code that implements this:

```py
import io

import pandas
import numpy
import librosa


def read_data(f, date_format):
    df = pandas.read_csv(f, sep=',')

    # Use proper pandas datatypes
    df['Time'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['DateTimeStamp'], format=date_format)
    df['Duration'] = pandas.to_timedelta(df['Duration ms'], unit='ms')
    df = df.drop(columns=['DateTimeStamp', 'Duration ms'])

    # Compute start and end time of each segment
    # audio starts at time of first segment
    first = df['Time'].iloc[0]
    df['Start'] = df['Time'] - first
    df['End'] = df['Start'] + df['Duration']

    return df

def extract_segments(y, sr, segments):
    # compute segment regions in number of samples
    starts = numpy.floor(segments.Start.dt.total_seconds() * sr).astype(int)
    ends = numpy.ceil(segments.End.dt.total_seconds() * sr).astype(int)

    # slice the audio into segments
    for start, end in zip(starts, ends):
        audio_seg = y[start:end]
        print('extracting audio segment:', len(audio_seg), 'samples')

## Reproducible example
data = io.StringIO("""DateTimeStamp,Action,Duration ms
04/16/20 21:25:36:241,A,502
04/16/20 21:25:36:317,B,2253
04/16/20 21:25:36:734,X,118
04/16/20 21:25:36:837,C,10
04/16/20 21:25:37:537,D,797
04/16/20 21:25:37:606,X,70
04/16/20 21:25:37:874,A,1506
""")

segments = read_data(data, date_format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%f")
print(segments)

path = librosa.util.example_audio_file()
y, sr = librosa.load(path, sr=16000, duration=10)
extract_segments(y, sr, segments)
```

should output something like

```
 Action                    Time        Duration           Start             End
0      A 2020-04-16 21:25:36.241 00:00:00.502000        00:00:00 00:00:00.502000
1      B 2020-04-16 21:25:36.317 00:00:02.253000 00:00:00.076000 00:00:02.329000
2      X 2020-04-16 21:25:36.734 00:00:00.118000 00:00:00.493000 00:00:00.611000
3      C 2020-04-16 21:25:36.837 00:00:00.010000 00:00:00.596000 00:00:00.606000
4      D 2020-04-16 21:25:37.537 00:00:00.797000 00:00:01.296000 00:00:02.093000
5      X 2020-04-16 21:25:37.606 00:00:00.070000 00:00:01.365000 00:00:01.435000
6      A 2020-04-16 21:25:37.874 00:00:01.506000 00:00:01.633000 00:00:03.139000
extracting audio segment: 8032 samples
extracting audio segment: 36048 samples
extracting audio segment: 1888 samples
extracting audio segment: 160 samples
extracting audio segment: 12752 samples
extracting audio segment: 1120 samples
extracting audio segment: 24097 samples
```

Comment: As a Python beginner, I'm facing a couple of problems. How can I use the files annot.csv and audio.wav in the example above?

Comment: Use pandas.read_csv() with your annot.csv to get a DataFrame with the segments. And set audio.wav as the path

Comment: Thanks. I'm struggling with this issue: 'segments = read.data(df, date_format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%f")
print(segments)' results in the error "df not defined". Do you have a suggestion how to fix that?

Comment: df not defined means exactly that, the variable has not been defined. But also read_data takes a path, not a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: So, I would rather use the command: "segments = read_data(f, date_format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%f")" with "f" being the path to my "annot.csv" file. Does this sound right? Sorry, still learning.

Comment: Yes. The name of the variable could be something different from "f" though. Like "path"

Comment: I understand now, thanks! How can I then retrieve the audio segments in .wav format? I imagine it should be possible to extract all the audio segments and store them with the "Action" label and the DateTimeStamp, right?

Comment: The code shows the cutting of the audio data into sections. If you want to save those as separate wav files then use pysoundfile write to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying something like: "def write_wav(wavseg, segments, sr=16000, format="WAV"): soundfile.write('wavseg.wav', segments, sr=16000, format="WAV")". Is this the right direction to go? Thanks again for the great help.

Comment: audio_seg is the segment of audio, that you should write out. And each segment must have a unique filename

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm slowly getting there. Would you be able to help me to choose the most elegant code for adding the string in the  "action" column to the filenames of the respective audio_seg segments to be saved?

Comment: Thanks. I struggle to put this into the correct code apparently.

Answer (score 0):

```
import io
import pandas
import numpy as np
import librosa
import soundfile as sf
def read_data(annot, date_format):
  df = pandas.read_csv(annot, sep=',')

  # Use proper pandas datatypes
  df['Time'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format=date_format)
  df['Duration'] = pandas.to_timedelta(df['Duration ms'], unit='ms')
  df = df.drop(columns=['DateTime', 'Duration ms'])

  # Compute start and end time of each segment
  # audio starts at time of first segment
  first = df['Time'].iloc[0]
  df['Start'] = df['Time'] - first
  df['End'] = df['Start'] + df['Duration']

  return df

def extract_segments(y, sr, segments):
  # compute segment regions in number of samples
  starts = np.floor(segments.Start.dt.total_seconds() * sr).astype(int)
  ends = np.ceil(segments.End.dt.total_seconds() * sr).astype(int)

  # slice the audio into segments
  i = 0
  for start, end in zip(starts, ends):
    audio_seg = y[start:end]
    print('extracting audio segment:', len(audio_seg), 'samples')
    
    # file name string
    # it takes 5 first character of Action
    # and converts start and end time 
    file_name = str(segments.Activity[i][:5]) + \
    '__' + \
    str(segments.Start[i]).split('s ')[1].replace(':','_') + \
    '__' + \
    str(segments.End[i]).split('s ')[1].replace(':','_') + ".wav"
    
    sf.write(file_name, audio_seg, sr)
    i += 1
segments = read_data("annot.csv", date_format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%f")
segments

y, sr = librosa.load("audio.wav", sr=16000, duration=2027)
extract_segments(y, sr, segments)
```